# How to calculate pixel per meter in Box2d and LIbgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, orthographic

I set my orthographic camera for my box2d world to 21 width and 12 height, this is equivalent to 1 meter = 1 pixel. But the problem is that I have another ortho camera for my sprites and bitmapfonts (for my SpriteBatch) which is 640X360 pixels, so for example I have a 1x1 meter body then how can I render the texture on top of that body as big as 1x1 meter into pixel?

Comment: http://blog.xoppa.com/pixels

Comment: I have personally used a ScreenViewport which has methods for getting and setting the units per pixel. When drawing in screen space I simply divide the world coordinates (in metres) by the ScreenViewport.getUnitsPerPixel() value which converts them to pixel coordinates.

Comment: Surely your texture would end up being one pixel by one pixel?

Answer (score 0):

First, don't think of camera units as pixels,I suggest you use a single camera and "units per meter" multiplier for conversion.

set your camera's width and height as how much of your world you wish to be seen. set size of your sprites using `setSize()` method, it will scale your texture to be seen as the proportion of world; if you want one meter to be 1/10 of screen height
set a variable like
`upm= camera.viewportHeight/10 //units per meter`
so that you can set size of e.g. 2×1 box as
`myBoxSprite.setSize(2*upm,upm)`. box2d `Body` has `setUserData()` and `getUserData()` methods which you can use to link your sprites(visual game objects) to their box2d body(physical body) and access it when needed and also make  referrence variables in your game object to point to box2d body and sprite like so you can use them when you want to change position of sprite to be drawn according to body's position

p.s. this is my first answer on SOF so excuse me if it is not as it has to be.